# odoo 14 pivot measure limit

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-view, odoo-14

I was trying to create pivot table but i am not sure if what a want can be done using a pivot View

| Customer | Tolat | Total today | last 7 days | last 30 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 1000 | 200 | 350 | 1000 |
| name 2 | 5000 | 0 | 4000 | 5000 |

This is what I have until now

`domain="[('date_order','&gt;', (context_today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d') )]"`

```
           <pivot string="n_account_move_pivot" disable_linking="true">

                    <field name="partner_id" type="row"/>

                    <field name="date" type="col" interval="month"/>

                    <field name="amount_total_signed" type="measure"/>
                    
           </pivot>
```

I tried setting a domain but odoo basically called me an idiot
`domain="[('date','&gt;', (context_today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d') )]"`

and also tried to used a datetime `2018-12-19 09:26:03.478039` in the interval

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What do you want to achieve? What is your data base for the pivot view?

Comment: the date is from the invoices recored, it is like the aged report but for posted invoices in pivot format @CZoellner